# How to get a better column edit mode in vim (more visualizable and customizable)

Tags: vim

Vi experts, I have two questions concerning the column editing!

First, I already know how to go to the visual mode and do a column edit. But the point is that after <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and type, you can only see the first row changing before <kbd>esc</kbd>. My question is this, is it possible to make the editing operation visible in all rows? Or is this still an impossible task with the current vim?

My second question is, I want to insert a column with increasing numbers (`0...9`) or some user defined increasing items such as (`monday...sunday`) blahblah, what is the best way to achieve this, can I define a few customized functions and then call them?

Comment: Sorry for asking two questions in one post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Still an impossible task" exposes a wrong assumption: Vim never wanted to be a WYSIWYG editor; just updating the current row requires less screen updates (which can be significant over slow connections; the whole modal editing of vi was partly born out of that necessity).

There are some attempts at "multiple cursors" plugins; with those, you might achieve this, though.

#### second question

<sup>(Note that it is bad style to ask about two unrelated things in a single question.)</sup>

Yes, you can do almost anything in "a few customized functions" (but you'd have to clarify your exact use case to get meaningful answers).

Some of that can be done via the [speeddating plugin](https://github.com/tpope/vim-speeddating):

> `{Visual}<C-A>`           Increment by [count] the component under the cursor on each line of the linewise visual selection.  If a component is absent on a line, it is filled in as being [count] higher than on the line above it.  This can be used to create sequences.  For example, place a "0" on a line followed by 4 blank lines, visually select all 5 lines, and press `<C-A>` to get a sequence of 1 through 5.  You can use letters in visual mode too: make the first entry Z if you want a list starting with A.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll take a look. If vi is going to suffer the screen updates with multiple-cursors in slow connections, will other editors be any better off?

Comment: No, in terms of bandwidth requirements, most other editors won't be better. With today's abundant bandwidth, this is increasingly irrelevant, but it's useful to know where Vim comes from.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. For those who have the same question as I have, I found this plugin works like a charm. (https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors).